# Nodejs node-gyp build for both windows and linux

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm creating a nodejs App and packaging with pkg for both windows and linux, I'm using a windows pc and was wondering if there was a way to build a cpp file for both linux and windows using node-gyp on my windows pc.

I was thinking of building and packaging for windows then rebuild the project under an linux version of node but don't know how to do it?

Comment: can you not perform this build step in a postinstall script? Edit: ah, I missed that you were performing some kind of packaging of your app.

Comment: So im running `node-gyp rebuild` then packing using pkg, when rebuildind some modules create a .node executable problem is that they are compiled for windows and not linux